# Program to static-link VB6 executable to it's dependencies (like PowerRap)

Tags: vb6, static-linking

I read something about PowerWrap which is supposed to allow you to static-link a vb6 .exe to it's dependent files (.OCX, etc.)

However, the [website for the product](http://www.moonlight-software.com/vbpower.htm) appears to be just a squatter.

Anyone know anything more about the product or something similar that's still being supported?

Comment: These tend to be pretty flaky, often ending by leaving corrupted entries in the registry and breaking any other applications that use the same components.  They do not statically link anything, but instead fiddle around a lot at runtime dumping resources out as files and self-registering them.  "Installation package authors are strongly advised against using self registration." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371608(VS.85).aspx

Comment: I advise you to try out registry-free COM instead, maybe with Make My Manifest. This turns your app into a set of related files that can simply be copied onto the target machine with no install, no registering. It's as close to a static linker as you'll get with VB6.

Comment: Make My Manifest is here http://mmm4vb6.atom5.com/

Answer (score 1):

I discovered another solution called UMM ([Universal Make My Manifest](https://github.com/wqweto/UMMM)). You give it a list of files and some options, and out comes a manifest ready-to-go. I've been using it for a half-million line VB project with dozens of ActiveX modules, and it works well. Requires `tlbinf32.dll`.

Comment: Side-by-side execution with a manifest seems like the closest you can get to static linking with VB6